# Timeout subprocess while reading stdout realtime

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT, TimeoutExpired

cmd = 'for x in $(seq 1 3); do echo stage $x; sleep 1; done'

proc = Popen(cmd, shell=True, close_fds=True,
             stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
             universal_newlines=True, start_new_session=True)              

for line in proc.stdout:
     print(line.strip())
```

Default behavior of `communicate` is to spit out all `stdout` after the proc. is terminated. However I need access to `stdout` while proc. is still running, but terminate it, if it's running too long.

***EDIT***

The following seem to work the way I want, not sure if that's correct approach?

```
from os import killpg
from signal import SIGKILL
from concurrent import futures
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT, TimeoutExpired

cmd = 'for x in $(seq 1 3); do echo stage $x; sleep 1; done'

proc = Popen(cmd, shell=True, close_fds=True,
             stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
             universal_newlines=True, start_new_session=True)

def handler(proc, timeout=None):
    try:
        proc.wait(timeout)
    except TimeoutExpired as err:
        print(err)
        killpg(proc.pid, SIGKILL)

exe = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)  
exe.submit(handler, proc, 2)

for line in proc.stdout:
     print(line.strip())
```

Comment: have you tried using Popen.wait(timeout) ? it's in the popen objects. But as you use stdout, you may use popen.communicate to avoid being blocked ...

Comment: If I'll `wait()` it will block the same way `communicate()` does, so I won't be able to read `stdout` until it finish waiting